# Asp.NET or Silverlight for a reports generator application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, reporting

I'm asked to develop a Reports generator (like Pentaho one) using ASP.NET (not an obligation). But I'm considering the use of Silverlight. I'm dealing with data that could have multiple sources. I've read that Silverlight isn't good enough in case a lot of data is loaded at once. So my question is: Which is better ASP.net ( with jscript, Ajax...) or Silverlight for a reporting application?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. Do you want develop a new reporting tool? There are already a large count of tools. Why you does not use one of the existing report generators?

And for your question Silverlight vs Ajax you need to write more what you want. The data will fetch on the server. The client see only the current page. In general on a client a Ajax or Java solution is better because over 95% of the clients have it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that matter, for you. But it you need to print from the application, I would say that it is easier to go with ASP.NET as the print api in Silverlight is not that great.
(getting a little better in SL5 though)

Wether you use silverlight or asp.net, loading huge amount of data is never a good idea, so the problem is the same here. You never really want to display 10 000 lines of report on one page.

I would go with an asp.net website personally, as you will get out of the box the things like deep linking, or print, that you will have to develop in the silverlight application

Then, I don't know your background, but silverlight is VERY different from a web app, and if you never worked with it, it will take some time before you are productive.

Finally, if you plan on unit testing your app, it is a **PAIN** in silverlight.

Answer (score -1):

how about using a 3rd party tool like [List and Label](http://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/.NET-Visual-Studio-WPF)?
would simplify things, royalty free distribution is included...